# Which construction is correct, "astonished finding" or "astonished to find"?

Tags: single-word-requests, prepositions

Like,

> We were astonished finding the cat climbing the tree itself.

or

> We were astonished to find the cat.

Comment: The grammar of both sentences is correct, but the second one, "We were astonished to find the cat climbing the tree itself", makes much better sense.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct - but the implications are ever so slightly different.

In the first sentence, 'we were astonished finding the cat' has the sense that you were astonished while finding the cat.

In the latter 'we were astonished to find' has more of a direct meaning, in which the finding of the cat triggered the astonishment. This one is much more common (rarely is the former used specifically) and so I'd say that 'we were astonished to find the cat climbing the tree itself' is probably more appropriate.